# Variable values not being saved after being updated in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to use a for loop to update previously declared variables, and within the loop the variable values are updating fine (using the print statement to check). However, after the loop ends, if I check the values with a print statement outside the loop, they are the same as they were before the loop and haven't updated for me to use elsewhere.

```
public class Intervals {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Declaring necessary constants
    int MINUTES_IN_DAY = 1440;
    int MINUTES_IN_HOUR = 60;

    // Take user inputs for interval start and end times in hours
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the earlier interval's start and end time in 24-hour time format. ");
    int intervalStart1 = input.nextInt();
    int intervalEnd1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the later interval's start and end time in 24-hour time format. ");
    int intervalStart2 = input.nextInt();
    int intervalEnd2 = input.nextInt();


    // For-each loop that converts all 24-hour times to minutes after midnight
    int times[] = {intervalStart1, intervalEnd1, intervalStart2, intervalEnd2};
    for (int i: times) {
        i = (i / 100 * MINUTES_IN_HOUR) + (i % 100);
        System.out.println("the interval is " + i);
    }

    // ERROR: values from for loop are not being saved, so variable values are not being updated as shown in next print line.

    System.out.println(intervalStart1);
```

Comment: in your loop, the only value you update is i, which is a local variable in the scope of the loop. This variable seizes to exist once the loop is finished.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way for me to use a loop to update the variables globally instead of locally?

Comment: which variable are you trying to update?

Comment: I'm trying to modify all the variables in the array without writing out four separate conversion statements.

Comment: I've found my answer; thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making two incorrect assumptions.

1. Assigning values to the loop variable of the enhanced for loop doesn't change the corresponding element of the array (or `Iterable`) you are iterating over. Your loop is equivalent to:

   ```
   for (int index = 0; index < times.length; index++) {
       int i = times[index];
       i = (i / 100 * MINUTES_IN_HOUR) + (i % 100);
       System.out.println("the interval is " + i);
   }
   ```

   which clearly doesn't update the values in the array. In order to modify the array, you'll have to write:

   ```
   for (int index = 0; index < times.length; index++) {
       times[index] = (times[index] / 100 * MINUTES_IN_HOUR) + (times[index] % 100);
       System.out.println("the interval is " + times[index]);
   }
   ```
2. Your array contains values initialized from other variables (such as `intervalStart1`). Even if you changed the values in your array (which you don't), that wouldn't change the values of the original variables.

Comment: I understand now why the values aren't changing. So how can I modify the values of the original variables instead of just modifying the array?

Comment: @marsiwala you have to modify the original variables after the loop. For example: `intervalStart1 = times[0]`. I'd consider getting rid of the original variables and using just the array.

Comment: Since I'm asking for a user input, don't I need the original variables to provide a value for the array? Sorry, I'm still pretty new at this.

Comment: @marsiwala you can initialize the array with `int[] times = new int[4]`; Then assign the user input to `times[0]`, `times[1]`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
int times[] = {intervalStart1, intervalEnd1, intervalStart2, intervalEnd2};
for (int i: times) {
    i = (i / 100 * MINUTES_IN_HOUR) + (i % 100);
    System.out.println("the interval is " + i);
}
```

`i` is a copy of the values in the array, it doesn't act like a pointer, updating `i` will only update the copy, which is thrown away on the next loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you are not updating them, after you got the value `i` it will no more be referring to the value in the array. it is a copy.

```
   int times[] = {intervalStart1, intervalEnd1, intervalStart2, intervalEnd2};
    for (int i: times) {
        i = (i / 100 * MINUTES_IN_HOUR) + (i % 100);
        System.out.println("the interval is " + i);
    }
```

to update you have to modifiy them inside your loop, use some `index` variable to access the elements and update them

```
  int index=0;
  int times[] = {intervalStart1, intervalEnd1, intervalStart2, intervalEnd2};
    for (int i: times) {
        times[index++] = (i / 100 * MINUTES_IN_HOUR) + (i % 100);
        System.out.println("the interval is " + i);
    }

System.out.println(times[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand it now.

Comment: @marsiwala That still won't update the original variables (intervalStart1, intervalEnd1, etc...)

Comment: @Eran can you explain why?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod The array holds copies of the values of the original variables. If you assign new values to the array, the values of the original variables used to initialize the array are unaffected.

Comment: the assignment happens after expression is computed so array will hold the new values based on the expression `intervalStart1 = intervalStart1/100 * MINUTES_IN_HOUR) + (intervalStart1 % 100`

Comment: @TheScientificMethod yes, the array will hold the updated values after your loop, but the OP expected the original variables to hold the updated values too. (see the `ERROR: values from for loop are not being saved, so variable values are not being updated as shown in next print line.` comment)

Comment: Yes, I should have been clearer in my original question. I wanted to update the original variables instead of the values in the arrays. I've found my answer now; thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
// For-each loop that converts all 24-hour times to minutes after midnight
int times[] = {intervalStart1, intervalEnd1, intervalStart2, intervalEnd2};
for (int i: times) {
    i = (i / 100 * MINUTES_IN_HOUR) + (i % 100);
    System.out.println("the interval is " + i);
}

// ERROR: values from for loop are not being saved, so variable values are not being updated as shown in next print line.

System.out.println(intervalStart1);`
```

I think you want to update values of times[] array right ?

so if you want to update this do 1 thing use normal loop i.e

```
for(int i =0;  i < times.length;i++){
  times[i] = (times[i]/100*MINUTES_IN_HOUR) + (I % 100);
  System.out.println("the interval is  "+times[i]);
}
System.out.println(times[0]);`
```

But consider one thing if you want to update the

> intervalStart1

variable then you have to assign this values from the times array after loop.

I hope it will works for you.